# Как сделать такие шрифты?

Tags: css

Здравствуйте. Как можно сделать [такие шрифты, как здесь](http://networkingday.ru/)?

Насколько я понимаю, здесь не `CSS` это решается.

Comment: скриншот из google maps - это сильно

Comment: Вопрос был не о скриншоте :) О шрифтах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как раз-таки css. Используйте @font-face

Comment: там даже в исходниках файл fonts.css подключается

Comment: А что означает @font-face ?

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/css/font-face

Вот генератор font-face: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator/

Заливаете шрифт в ttf получается готовую страничку с шрифтами

Answer (score 0):

Скачайте шрифт Code Bold он такой же как на том сайте!

```
<p class=MsoNormal>
  <span class=GramE>
    <span lang=EN-US style='font-size: 48.0pt; font-family: "Code Bold"; mso-ansi-language:EN-US'>This Text?</span>
    </span>
  <span lang=EN-US style='font-size:48.0pt; font-family: "Code Bold"; mso-ansi-language: EN-US'>
    <o:p></o:p>
  </span>
</p>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Dawnload Font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zw5d.png)

CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Code Bold; /* Имя шрифта */
  src: url(fonts/codebold.ttf); /* Путь к файлу со шрифтом */
}

P {
  font-family: Code Bold;
}
```